# some menus in navbar only visible with xs view-mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want some menus only appear in collapsed navbar.

with no responsive tag, unwanted menu (g4 manual/g4 skin/g4 requirement) shows in navbar.
(http://www.bootply.com/OpenCode/100726)

with "hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" tag, collapsed menu does not shown in xs view.
(http://www.bootply.com/OpenCode/100727)

with "hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" tag, collapsed menu does not shown in xs view.
menu apprear and duplicated.

I do many try, but can not found answer.

some of codes...

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-top-member-collapse hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" role="menu">
            <li><a href="<?=$g4[bbs_path]?>/board.php?bo_table=gnu4_pack_book">g4 manual</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=$g4[bbs_path]?>/board.php?bo_table=gnu4_pack_skin">g4 skin</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=$g4[bbs_path]?>/board.php?bo_table=gnu4_pack_req">g4 requirement</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: with the code you give i see the menu only on xs-grid after removing  hidden-xs

Comment: if I remove hidden-xs, menu is visible in navbar always.

Comment: see: http://bootply.com/100747

Comment: In xs-mode, menus are visible and not collapsed. hidden-sm class make all visible menus appear even with collapse-xs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `hidden-xs`. I put them into a dropdown like the other items too...

```
    <li class="dropdown hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">g4 BOX<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="">g4 manual</a></li>
            <li><a href="">g4 skin</a></li>
            <li><a href="">g4 requirement</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

See it in action: http://www.bootply.com/jwQGciLMTo

**EDIT:**

There is also this if you don't want them in a dropdown within the collapsing nav: http://www.bootply.com/lZXTYXlWqg